# How do I register a nickname on freenode’s IRC network, using Colloquy?

Tags: macos, mac, irc, colloquy, freenode

Proper newbie IRC question here: in order to access the #django IRC channel on freenode, I need to register a nickname with freenode.

freenode’s instructions for that are here:

- http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#nicksetup

It says to send a message like the following via IRC:

```
/msg nickserv register <password> <email>
```

I’m using Colloquy on the Mac. How can I send a message like that using Colloquy? I’m not clear on how I can send IRC messages without already being in an IRC channel, and obviously sending a message including my password in an IRC channel, with other people able to see it, doesn’t sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you send it to a 'service', a special purpose bot. and you can send that message as soon as you are connected to the server.

- click to "chat.freenode.org"
- click 'console'
- enter:

```
/nick yournick
/msg NickServ register yourpass yourmail
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, once I’m connected to the server, the “Message User” icon in Colloquy is enabled. I sent `register <password> <email>` to the user `nickserv`, and it worked. Cheers!

Comment: or that way, i had to install that client. real men use irssi :)

Comment: ok. That is fine. I have registered my nickname. But how can I get the registered nickname when I login to http://webchat.freenode.net/ irc?

Comment: @ARUN: you fill out the form on webchat.freenode.net, it's all there.

Comment: It's retarded that this simple answer is located nowhere but here, everyone who trys to explain just makes it worse. thank you!

Comment: Any chance of poasting how you login afterwards?

Comment: log into a channel? `/join #channel-name`

Comment: @akira was meaning in general, I found it though :) /msg nickserv identify AccountName Your-Password

Comment: then i did not understand your question about the "login afterwards"

Answer (score 7):

You can simply goto http://webchat.freenode.net and use the web chat interface to register.

[image]